# ¿Qué loop utilizar para encontrar solo un valor en PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Sólo quiero seleccionar un único valor de la base de datos y he leído que utilizar **foreach** en este caso es un error.

¿Qué debería cambiar en este código para hacerlo más **eficiente**?

Código:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('

    SELECT COUNT(customer_db_id) as NumberOfCustomersWithTODAY
    FROM `lithuania_customers_2016`
    WHEREcampaign_id = '.$campaign_id.'
    AND user_id = :user_id
');
$sth->execute(array(':user_id' => $agentID));

foreach ($sth as $row)
{  
    $NumberOfCustomersWithTODAY = $row['NumberOfCustomersWithTODAY'];
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde lo has leído?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hace falta que uses un loop si quieres sacar un solo valor o en tu caso `COUNT`.

Usando [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) puedes obtener el valor te tu consulta:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
           SELECT COUNT(customer_db_id) as NumberOfCustomersWithTODAY
           FROM `lithuania_customers_2016`
           WHERE campaign_id = '.$campaign_id.'
           AND user_id = :user_id
       ');  

    $sth->execute(array(':user_id' => $agentID));

    $file = $sth->fetch();

    $NumberOfCustomersWithTODAY = $file['NumberOfCustomersWithTODAY'];
```

*Nota aparte*: No se de donde sacas la variable `$campaign_id` pero ya que usas sentencias preparadas, lo añadiría también en el array:

```
$sth->execute(array(':user_id' => $agentID, ':campaign_id' => $campaign_id));
```

Comment: Entonce en SQL debería tener: WHERE campaign_id = :campaign_id ?  @aldanux muchas gracias !

Comment: @Lukas - Exacto

Comment: Tambien puedes utilizar $NumberOfCustomersWithToday = $sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que esta consulta solo te devuelve un único resultado (estas haciendo un conteo, por lo que tendrás un número). No necesitas usar un bucle para acceder al mismo, el acceso sería directo, de ahí lo ineficiente del *foreach*.

Si tienes configurado PDO para devolverte un array, tienes el resultado con:

```
$row = $query->fetch()
$res = $row[ 0 ];
```

y si esperas objetos:

```
$row = $query->fetch()
$res = $row->NumberOfCustomersWithTODAY;
```